# Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

When I included the jquery mobile javascript file in to the code in order to recognize the tap and tap hold events, in the following code

```
$("#applyZoom").live("tap", function(event){
    alert('binding');
});
```

I am getting the error "**Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.**"
in the chrome browser.
When I tested in the IOS simulator, no other click event is working.
I am not using any ajax call.

Please help me out to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 0):

What is the jQuery library are you using? `live` is depreciated as of 1.9. You should use `on` instead of `live`. Check whether it solves the issue.

As per the [documentation](http://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/) you should do something as below

```
$( "#applyZoom" ).on( 'tap', tapHandler );
function tapHandler( event ) {
    alert("all set");
}
```

I suppose you are trying to run the files from local directory, instead of a hosted solution. Try to host it in localhost and access via http and see whether you get null origin error. Else try to access via `file:///` like url and see.